# Regex single-line multiple match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

With `preg_replace` in PHP, I am trying to match a regex pattern multiple times in a string, sometimes there will be 2 matches on 1 lines, sometimes not.

I have the following string:

```
 $text = 'Check <a href="link1">text1</a> or <a href="link2">text2</a>
 oh
 well <a href="link3">text3</a>';
```

I would like it to convert to:

```
 Check
 text1
 link1
 or
 text2
 link2
 oh
 well
 text3
 link3
```

I have this:

```
 $text = preg_replace('/(<a href=")(.+)(">)(.*)(<\/a>)/', "\n$4\n$2\n", $text);
```

But it doesn't work, only when having 1 match at a line. Like:

```
 $text = 'Check <a href="link1">text1</a> 
 or <a href="link2">text2</a>
 oh
 well <a href="link3">text3</a>';
```

Any help appreciated.

Example with a and b
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/4fU

Comment: Does `link1` and `text1` really need to be in reverse order in your result string?

Comment: Well, preferable, but not 100% necessary. It's more clear to a user. I am trying to create a plain-text mail that will be parsed for a HTML mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over all text nodes you can find inside the given HTML and create a special case for parent anchors:

```
$text = 'Check <a href="link1">text1</a> or <a href="link2">text2</a>
 oh
 well <a href="link3">text3</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//text()') as $node) {
  if ($node->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        echo $node->textContent, "\n";
        if ($node->parentNode->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && $node->parentNode->nodeName == 'a') {
                echo $node->parentNode->getAttribute('href'), "\n";
        }
  }
}
```

In a textual domain, you would do it like this:

```
echo preg_replace('~<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</a>~i', "\n\$2\n\$1", $text);
```

Basically you use negative character sets for the href and tag contents enclosure instead of simply `.+` and `.*` because those are greedy by default; this can be changed by using `.+?` and `.*?` respectively, but a negative character set would lead to less backtracking.

Also, you only need to perform memory captures on two parts of the anchor, not all five of them.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to understand how to solve this with preg_replace

Comment: Since I can reuse this pattern for non-HTML situations if I understand it.

Comment: Thanks, but now I see an issue when the enclosed text1, text2, text3 has HTML tags as well `<a href="link1"><strong>text1</strong></a>`

Comment: @Sanne That's what I'm telling you that this is not a text problem. Problems in HTML are solved in another way.

Comment: Your other code also has problems with enclosing tags. The link gets removed.

Comment: Just so you know - I opened another question specifically about the DOM solution. I understand that this is the way to go when replacing stuff in HTML.. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

NOT for your problem but you can add modifiers to a regex pattern after last slash:

preg_replace('/whatever_my_pattern_do/MODIFIERS',"here I replace", $text);

You should check them all [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: There's no `g` flag in PCRE. `preg_replace()` by default replaces **all** the occurrences.

Comment: Wop, you're right I'll edit the comment then, thank you!